# manipulate content in a chrome extension's popup with yours

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to trigger a button click on another chrome extension from mine, and I do not know if it is even possible, plus I did not find any resources. So, how do I trigger a button click on any other chrome extension that I don't have access to?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: if you don't have access to that extension the answer is: you cannot.

Comment: You can use chrome.debugger API.